# how to add different layouts/items in navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have been trying to add some other things (like an image view or a text view) in my navigation drawer. My nav. drawer already has a list view, which is working fine, plz tell me how to add other things inside the drawer, just as in google+ nav. drawer.
plz give code if possible.
Tx in advance.

this is my xml for drawer layout

```
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

Comment: I would really appreciate if u plz get me an ans for this rather than pulling my leg.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. By using multiple 'layouts' and 'android:weight' you can add whatever you like in the 'LinearLayout', and also have a 'ListView' like I.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullRightLayout"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Anders Andersson"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list_right"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your listview in some linearlayout and put there what you want

Comment: i am afraid if it worked for u...! i already have tried it, it does not fit.

Comment: Its work for me for sure. You can do even more - you can extract this layout to separate xml and then reuse it as include if needed